# Activity after closing remains hanging in the list of open applications

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I create a notification and by clicking on it I create activity. But when I close activity, that visually it is closed, but remains hanging in the list of open applications. How to close activity caused in this way?

```
// I create a notification
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("text", text);

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

Notification n = new Notification.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
    .setAutoCancel(true).build();

notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, n);

// I close activity, which is shown by clicking on the notification
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonClose:
            finish();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

That is activity disappears from the screen, but if you open the open applications on your device, you can see it there.

Comment: Well, it is not really open applications but recent applications. And, currently there is no way we can remove it from there through code.

Comment: Are you possibly confusing "open applications" with "recent apps"?  If you want to keep your app from showing there, use `android:excludeFromRecents` activity flag.